# Not getting the last list element text value when implementing POM in Cucumber Selenium JS

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, pom.xml

I'm trying to use POM model where I put all my web elements in a seperate page. What I did is create a new function and call it in my step_definition folder.

I'm writing a script that if I enter a to-do list item, it should be added last to the current list of items. However, it always gets the 2nd to the last item if I use as xpath: `//li[last()]`

Here's the script in the step_definition folder:

```
When('User adds a task', async function () {
    loginPage.enter_toDo("Learn Selenium")
});

Then('task is added', async function () {
    let toDoText = await loginPage.getLastItem().getText().then(function(value) {
        return value
    })
    assert.equal(toDoText, "Learn Selenium");
```

Here are the functions in the page_object folder:

```
class LoginPage extends BasePage {
    async enter_toDo(toDoText) {
        await driver.findElement(By.id("sampletodotext")).sendKeys('Learn Selenium',Key.RETURN);
    }

    getLastItem () {
        return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[last()]"))
    }

}
```

I'm expecting to get "Learn Selenium" but I always end up with the 2nd to the last item. I tried replacing `loginPage.enter_toDo("Learn Selenium")` with `await driver.findElement(By.id("sampletodotext")).sendKeys('Learn Selenium',Key.RETURN);` in the step_definition and it works, but this defeat the purpose of POM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed `await` in `loginPage.enter_toDo`.

I guess, when you trying to `sendKeys` into input, last li element is appeared.

`enter_toDo` function is `async`, so when you calling it in `When` block without awaiting for Promise to be resolved, `Then` is executed while Promise of `loginPage.enter_toDo` is in Pending state.

Modify your code as follows:

```js
When('User adds a task', async function () {
    await loginPage.enter_toDo("Learn Selenium")
});
```

Comment: @JohnRamos can you mark this post as answered if it works for you? :)

Answer (score 0):

Update your getLastItem method in the Page Object to use WebDriverWait.

```js
const { By, Key, until } = require('selenium-webdriver');

class LoginPage extends BasePage {
    async enter_toDo(toDoText) {
        await driver.findElement(By.id("sampletodotext")).sendKeys(toDoText, Key.RETURN);
    }

    async getLastItem() {
        const lastItem = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.xpath("//li[last()]")), 5000); // Adjust the timeout as needed
        return lastItem;
    }
}
```

Modify the step definitions to await the getLastItem method will solve this.

```js
When('User adds a task', async function () {
    await loginPage.enter_toDo("Learn Selenium");
});

Then('task is added', async function () {
    let toDoText = await loginPage.getLastItem().getText();
    assert.equal(toDoText, "Learn Selenium");
});
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when I copied it:

TypeError: loginPage.getLastItem(...).getText is not a function